# I18n and the snowman param conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, rails-i18n

I am using rails internationalization, so my URLs seem like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/index?locale=es
```

I have a form with get method which appends the snowman param to the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/index?locale=es?utf8=%E2%9C%93&dateregistration=2013-06-20
```

instead:

```
    http://localhost:3000/dashboard/index?locale=es&utf8=%E2%9C%93&dateregistration=2013-06-20
```

The problem is that if I reload the location (F5)... I observe that param locale is:

```
p locale
:"es?utf8=V"
```

instead:

```
p locale
:es
```

so I18n doesn't works correctly.

Any ideas or suggestions?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`?` should precede only the first parameter in a URL. The others should all be preceded with `&`.

So your form needs to produce the URL

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/index?locale=es&utf8=%E2%9C%93&dateregistration=2013-06-20
```

...note the `&` before `utf8`.

Comment: Thanks Chowlet, obviously this is the problem. I don't know how do that when I submit the form.

Comment: @user1364684: If you can show your form code, we might be able to help. Usually I'd expect it to Just Happen.